# Inequalities bound

Tags: inequality

If $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ are all real numbers and positive and $b\leq c$ and $d \leq e$. Under what condition is $\frac{b}{d} \leq \frac{c}{e}$ ? I have been trying to think about it but cannot come up with a condition. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what form of a "condition" the question is asking for, since "$\frac bd\le\frac ce$" is a simple condition already.

Comment: Yes I am looking for criteria that aren't equivalent to it.

Comment: *A priori*, supposing $d,e>0$ you have $\dfrac b e\le \dfrac cd$ on the contrary.

Comment: It seems like $b\le c$ and $d\le e$ tells us very little about whether $\frac bd \le \frac ce$. For example, by choosing $b,d$ from among small positive numbers and $c,e$ from much larger numbers, we can get any pair of positive ratios $(\frac bd,\frac ce)$, without violating $b\le c$ and $d\le e$.

Comment: Karl, you are right. However, I am trying to obtain the mathematical condition that summarizes everything you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume all numbers are positive then

$\frac bd \le \frac ce\iff$

$be \le dc$.

If we let $\delta = c-b \ge 0$ and $\gamma = e-d \ge 0$ then this is true if and only if

$b(d+\gamma) \le  d(b+\delta) \iff$

$b\gamma \le d\delta \iff$

$\frac {\gamma}{\delta} = \frac {e-d}{c-b} \le \frac db$.

That's something, I guess.  The inequality holds if the ratio of the differences is less than the ratio of the smaller values....

But ... is it useful.... Or easy to express?

Six of one half a dozen of the other, I guess.

(It's got the poetry of *sounding* like a formula "The ratio of the difference between the pairs is less or equal to the ratio of the smaller values of the pairs".  That *sounds* like it's important.  Even if it isn't.)

But we need to take cases where they *aren't* all positive.